# Access the name of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the data of pandas dataframe.

```
for i,row in stock.iterrows():
  pprint(row)
```

it returns data like this

```
Data             3.25000
Name: 2000-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

I can access `3.25000` as `row['Data']`, however `row['Name']` is unavailable.

How can I access `2000-01-03 00:00:00` ???

I have used dataframe with `index`.

`Name` means the same as `index`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Name` is index name.

You need `i` for index values:

```
for i,row in stock.iterrows():
    pprint(row)
    #index
    pprint(i)
```

Sample:

```
stock = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[3.5, 5.6]}, index=pd.date_range('2000-01-03', periods=2))
stock.index.name = 'Name'
print (stock)
            Data
Name            
2000-01-03   3.5
2000-01-04   5.6

print (stock.index.name)
Name

print (stock.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-03', '2000-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Name', freq='D')

for i,row in stock.iterrows():
    pprint(row)
    #index
    pprint(i)

Data    3.5
Name: 2000-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64
Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00', freq='D')
Data    5.6
Name: 2000-01-04 00:00:00, dtype: float64
Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

`index` name is converted to column name after [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
stock = stock.reset_index()
print (stock)
        Name  Data
0 2000-01-03   3.5
1 2000-01-04   5.6

print (stock.index.name)
None

print (stock.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

print (stock.columns)
Index(['Name', 'Data'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: THanks very much, I need to read the reference of pandas again. And your example is quite helpful!

Comment: @whitebear - Glad can help. Nice day!